# What's the difference between using single and double quotes in strings?

Tags: templating, string, difference

Is there a difference between using single-quoted and double-quoted strings?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a small difference, single-quoted strings don't support interpolation:

```
{% set string = 'There is a #{car}.' %}
```

The above example **won't** work. If you want to use it, you need to wrap your string in double quotes:

```
{% set string = "There is a #{car}." %}
```

Comment: This is similar to the PHP logic between single and double quotes.

Comment: Except that you can concatenate string in PHP using single quotes (using "."). Twig still requires double quotes (using "~").

Comment: @Bryan `{{ 'test' ~ 'String' }}` works for me.

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach Yep. You're right. I misread the Twig docs.